# Couchbase-lite-net building source files: How does one resolve 'was not found' dll errors

Tags: couchbase-lite

I have forked and cloned https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-net via GitHub windows client.

But, when I open the Couchbase.Lite.Net45.VS2013.sln and build. I get 10 errors stating that various dlls and 'metadata file' dlls could not be found.

Some error examples:

> Error 1   Could not copy the file
>   "C:\dev\repo_git\couchbase-lite-net\src\Couchbase.Lite.Shared\vendor\cbforest\CSharp\prebuilt\CBForest-Interop.dll"
>   because it was not found. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    3899    5   cbforest-sharp.Net45
>
> Error 2   Metadata file
>   'C:\dev\repo_git\couchbase-lite-net\src\Couchbase.Lite.Shared\vendor\cbforest\CSharp\cbforest-sharp.Net45\bin\Debug\cbforest-sharp.dll'
>   could not be
>   found C:\dev\repo_git\couchbase-lite-net\src\Couchbase.Lite.Net45\CSC Couchbase.Lite.Net45
>
> Error 10  Metadata file
>   'C:\dev\repo_git\couchbase-lite-net\src\ListenerComponent\Couchbase.Lite.Listener.Net45\bin\Debug\Couchbase.Lite.Listener.dll'
>   could not be
>   found C:\dev\repo_git\couchbase-lite-net\src\Couchbase.Lite.Net45.Tests\CSC   Couchbase.Lite.Net45.Tests

I noticed on the Github readme.md it states once needs to issue:

> git submodule update --init --recursive

But I think GitHub windows client already updated the submodules e.g. I can see many files in Couchbase.Lite.Shared\vendor\cbforest\CBForest but in CBForest example there is no "prebuilt\CBForest-Interop.dll" file.

**Update**
Got it working by building \src\Couchbase.Lite.Shared\vendor\cbforest\CBForest.VS2015 and copying the CBForest-Interop.dll into the above location

but still have 1 more build error:

> Error 107 Error reading resource file 'c:\dev\repo_git\couchbase-lite-net\src\Couchbase.Lite.Net45.Tests\Assets\local-test.properties' -- 'The system cannot find the file specified. '   C:\dev\repo_git\couchbase-lite-net\src\Couchbase.Lite.Net45.Tests\CSC   Couchbase.Lite.Net45.Tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved: see https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-net/issues/528 for details.